# Execute command more than once in the background (bash script)

Tags: linux, bash, process, background-process

I am writing a bash script in which I must execute 3 commands.

- Command `1` must run every 10 seconds, in the background
- Commands `2` and `3` must run once and also in the background.
- Also, command `1` must execute at least once, successfully, before command `2` and `3` execute, because it produces/updates a file that the last 2 will need for proper functioning.

However, I don't know how to make command `1` run with  these conditions... I cannot use a `while(1)` with a `sleep 10` or something of the kind, because then I would never reach the commands `2` and `3`.

What bash script concept am I missing? Threads, maybe?

**Edit:** Command `1` can be something as simple as incrementing integer number inside a .txt file and this file will be used in command `2` and `3`.

Comment: What if command 1 takes more than 10s to run?

Comment: I'm making sure it does not. But again, as I said, one part of the problem is that it must run at least once successfully, before the other two can be executed (so that command `2` and `3` have at least a file to work with, even if the contents are not updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What bash script concept am I missing? Threads, maybe?

Job control. You can start processes in the background and exercise fairly fine-grained control over them by knowing their process ID and exit status.

To get a backgrounded command's PID, use the `$!` variable.

To get a backgrounded command's exit status use `wait()` and provide its PID. **Note, calls to `wait()` will block if the command has not exited yet**. If this blocking is problem (it may be in your case), you can perform checks with `ps` (or some other method) before calling `wait()` to see if your process is ready to be reaped, usually in a loop where there is a watchdog or some other method of setting a limit on the task's execution time.

Consider the following cycle based boilerplate:

```
complete=0
cycles=0
# Task 1
sleep 200 &
pid=$!
while [[ complete -eq 0 ]]; then
    ps -o pid= -p $pid > /dev/null
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        # Signal complete to logic below
        complete=1
        break;
    fi
    # Perform some timeout / cycle check to give up on this task
    cycles=$((cycles + 1))
    if [[ $cycles -gt 100 ]]; then # whatever, this is just a simple watchdog example
        break;
    fi
    # Optional sleep
    sleep 1
done
if [[ $complete -eq 1 ]]; then
    # Process the command's exit status
    wait $pid
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        : # handle command failed perhaps
    else
        : # do other things, assuming exit of 0 is a good thing
    fi
else
    # Process a command watchdog failure
    kill -9 $pid # come what may
fi
```

For more complex job control, you can move your command checks and cycle management into bash functions and clean this code up a lot.